# Converting struts2 Dynamic web project to maven project, able to do mvn clean install but while launching application getting issue

Tags: java, maven, struts2

I have converted `struts2` dynamic web project to `maven` project.

I have added all dependencies which where there in WEB-INF/lib then deleted lib folder. After mvn clean install all jars added war same like `WEB-INF/lib`

**while launching application getting below error.**

```
000000b6 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[**com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor**]: **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter**
```

Comment: What version of S2? What does your pom file look like? You're likely missing a dependency in whatever is being deployed.

Comment: struts 2.5.22, I have added all dependencies. I thought need to add dependencies in deployment assembly then it will update in .settings 
how can i add from maven dependencies to deployment assembly